# Django Forms, Display Error on ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, validation, forms

I'm having an issue getting validation error messages to display for a particular field in a Django form, where the field in question is a **ModelMultipleChoiceField**.

In the `clean(self)` method for the Form, I try to add the error message to the field like so:

```
msg = 'error'
self._errors['field_name'] = ErrorList([msg])
raise forms.ValidationError(msg)
```

This works okay where 'field_name' points to other field types, but for ModelMultipleChoiceField it just won't display. Should this be handled differently?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it sounds like you're doing it wrong.

You should be using the [clean_](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) method instead. Read through that whole document, in fact - it's very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you instantiating an ErrorList and writing to self._errors directly? Calling "raise forms.ValidationError(msg)" takes care of all that already.

And what does your template look like?